# jQuery : Difference between String selector and function selector?

Tags: jquery

I really don't know how to name the 2 approaches so please pardon me for calling them as such.

String selector

```
$("#myList li").eq(3);
```

Function selector

```
$("#myList li:eq(3)");
```

From what I know, they both do the same thing or maybe I am wrong.

Is there any difference functionality or performance-wise?

Comment: Go and check the performance in JSPERF.com

Comment: http://jsperf.com/jquery-eq-method-vs-eq-pseudo-selector

Comment: Take a look at the "Additional Notes" section in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).

Comment: Ooh "pseudo selector", so that's its name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[:eq() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** is a jQuery extension.

Additional Note in the documentation:

> **Additional Notes:**
>
> Because **:eq() is a jQuery extension** and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :eq() **cannot** take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   **$("your-pure-css-selector").eq(index)** instead.

Comment: Will this hold true for all pseudo selectors?

Comment: @Kuma For the list of https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/jquery-selector-extensions/, it's true.

Answer (score 1):

[Check here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)

Quote:

> Wherever possible, make selections using IDs, class names, and tag names.

Basically, when you use CSS selectors compared to pseudo-selectors such as `:eq(3)` you will have better performance